# typeahead freezes in internet explorer

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have an input type textbox with typeahead in my angular application. In chrome it works fine but in IE it freezes.

Below is the code that i use  :

```html
<input id="typeahead-basic" [resultTemplate]="rt" [inputFormatter]="formatMatches" type="text" class="text-left form-control  form-control-sm mr-1"
                            [(ngModel)]="iLevelDataItem" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [ngbTypeahead]="search" placeholder="search iLevel data items">
```

There are around 250 items that i am loading into this but in IE it freezes. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I am getting this issue with 5 items as well

Comment: Any idea what could be the reason?